# Flutter Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: FN_AAPT2

Tags: flutter

[sdkmanager --update  get error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZPOEx.png)

I install flutter on windows but get error when run "sdkmanager --update".

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: FN_AAPT2
    at com.android.sdklib.BuildToolInfo.<init>(BuildToolInfo.java:362)
    at com.android.sdklib.BuildToolInfo.fromStandardDirectoryLayout(BuildToolInfo.java:233)
    at com.android.sdklib.repository.legacy.local.LocalSdk.scanBuildTools(LocalSdk.java:897)
    at com.android.sdklib.repository.legacy.local.LocalSdk.getPkgsInfos(LocalSdk.java:543)
    at com.android.sdklib.repository.legacy.LegacyLocalRepoLoader.parseLegacyLocalPackage(LegacyLocalRepoLoader.java:100)
    at com.android.repository.impl.manager.LocalRepoLoaderImpl.parsePackages(LocalRepoLoaderImpl.java:167)
    at com.android.repository.impl.manager.LocalRepoLoaderImpl.getPackages(LocalRepoLoaderImpl.java:124)
    at com.android.repository.impl.manager.RepoManagerImpl$LoadTask.run(RepoManagerImpl.java:518)
    at com.android.repository.api.RepoManager$DummyProgressRunner.runSyncWithProgress(RepoManager.java:397)
    at com.android.repository.impl.manager.RepoManagerImpl.load(RepoManagerImpl.java:365)
    at com.android.repository.api.RepoManager.loadSynchronously(RepoManager.java:290)
    at com.android.sdklib.repository.AndroidSdkHandler$RepoConfig.createRepoManager(AndroidSdkHandler.java:725)
    at com.android.sdklib.repository.AndroidSdkHandler.getSdkManager(AndroidSdkHandler.java:296)
    at com.android.sdklib.tool.sdkmanager.SdkManagerCliSettings.setSdkHandler(SdkManagerCliSettings.java:101)
    at com.android.sdklib.tool.sdkmanager.SdkManagerCli.<init>(SdkManagerCli.java:95)
    at com.android.sdklib.tool.sdkmanager.SdkManagerCli.main(SdkManagerCli.java:74)
    at com.android.sdklib.tool.sdkmanager.SdkManagerCli.main(SdkManagerCli.java:48)
```

how to fix it, somebody can be help me, thanks

Answer (score 0):

It's running OK now after I reinstall the sdkmanager.